Passing Makefile Variables into Linux Kernel Modules
I'd like to grab information from the shell and pass it into a kernel module through the makefile. I can do this with user space programs using -D.
Is there a similar mechanism for kernel modules? For example, if I define a makefile variable
CURRENT_DATE := '"$(shell date +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")"'
I can get a hold of that date as a string in a user space program by appending a -DCURRENT_DATE to the end of the build command. The variable CURRENT_DATE becomes available to the application as a 40-character string that I can copy when the application starts. Is there a similar mechanism for kernel module makefiles?

Just a sidebar, this does not work well with industry moving toward recreatable and immutable object and executable files.

-D is used for assigning macros that are used when compiling the program. Why would that be any different if the program you're compiling is a kernel module?

This question is similar to: Predefine a macro in kernel module. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
